# Random.choice Equivalent in Java for an Array

Tags: java, netbeans, python-3.4

Here is an example of my `random.choice` implementation in Python.

```
available_cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Queen', 'King', 'Jack', 'Ace']
random_computer_card = random.choice(available_cards)
print random_computer_card
```

Just wondering what the Java equivalent would be for this piece of code. Obviously I haven't included the `import` statement in the sample.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert everything to String and define them in an array like below and access from index by generating random number:

```
String[] available_cards = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Queen", "King", "Jack", "Ace"};  
java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
int random_computer_card = random.nextInt(available_cards.length);
System.out.println(available_cards[random_computer_card]);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, would an import statement still need to be used, if so, would this be the same as python?

Comment: @PythonBoy69 See above. It depends whether you need to import or you want to use fully qualified package (module in python) name

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would create an Enum for this because its clearly a set of predefined constant values.

```
public enum Rank {
     ONE,
     TWO,
     ...,
     ACE;
}
```

Then generate a random number in the bounds of the array (using `nextInt(int bound)`) and get the resulting value from the array of enum values.

```
Rank allRanks = Rank.values(); //get the array of ranks
int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(allRanks.length); //generate a random number in [0; allRanks.length-1]
Rank randomRank = allRanks[randomNum]; //get the random rank from the array
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Random` class.

like this:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(14);
```

and then do a switch on `randomInt` according to your array.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62

Comment: no, almas' answer above describes how to handle String for this

Comment: I have realised this now, thanks very much for your answer too, that link is great.